# Trying to rename PDFs and TXTs based off of information in the TXT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My code is able to rename the .txt file, but not able to target the pdf to rename at the same time with the same information extracted from the .txt file.

I've tried to put

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b *.pdf') do (
   rename "!fname!" "!nname!.pdf"
```

in different spots where I would think they might work, but if it's inside the other /f "delims="block for the .txt files, it does not run and if it's outside, it won't grab the same name.

```
setlocal
cd File Location


::Next Targets .txt files, makes variables, modifies the variable, and renames the .txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b *.txt') do (
   set "nname="
   set "fname=%%~i"
   for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%f in ("%%~i") do if not defined nname set "nname=%%f"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set "nname=!nname:~12,10!"
   rename "!fname!" "!nname!.txt"
)
::I tried to pull the same variables while targeting the .pdf files, but it wouldn't get the variables.
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b *.pdf') do ( 
   rename "!fname!" "!nname!.pdf"
)


endlocal
pause
```

I expected the second block to be able to pule the same variables(file names) from the first block, but it just does nothing.

Comment: at a rough glance, you need to have all of the same steps for your .PDF loop that you have for your .txt loop; as is - those for loops aren't connected in any way, so when your when your .PDF loop tries to find `!fname!` and `!nname! they don't exist.

Comment: well, I tried something like that before, but it reads the pdf as if you converted the pdf to a .txt. The issue there is that the pdf's converted to txt's look like a jumbled mess.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code block that would indicate you're renaming a .PDF to a .txt or vice versa, unless your source document includes file extensions in the lines. If you edit your question to show an example of what the lines look like in your source text, it might be more helpful.

Comment: Do the .txt and .pdf files have the same basename? test.txt and test.pdf? What information is in the .txt file that is extracted? Please copy/paste a few lines of the .txt file to be read into the question.

Comment: You appear to be trying to rename all `.txt` files in `File Location\ ` to characters `13..22` of line `5` from within themselves. As you've also mentioned, `.pdf`, are you expecting that your second `for` loop is capable of reading the fifth line of a [tag:pdf] in the same way as reading a plain [tag:txt] file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to rename the pdf's, as the txt's weren't necessary to rename, but instead to pull information from to rename the pdf's

```
setlocal
cd Directory
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b *.txt') do (
   set "nname="
   set "fname=%%~i"
   for /f "usebackq skip=5 delims=" %%f in ("%%~i") do if not defined nname set "nname=%%f"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set "nname=!nname:~12,10!"
   set "fname=!fname:~0,-4!"
   rename "!fname!.pdf" "!nname!.pdf"
)
endlocal
pause
```

This removes the ending to the variable and searches that +.pdf to rename